# Sencha production build failed while using sqlitestorage

Tags: sqlite, extjs, sencha-touch-2

[image]

In app.js file i have added path of sqlite folder

```
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Ext': 'touch/src',
    'ConsultLite': 'app',
    'Sqlite': 'sqlite'
});
```

My InitSQLite.js file is

```
Ext.define('ConsultLite.util.InitSQLite', {
singleton : true,
requires: [
   'Sqlite.Connection',
   'Sqlite.data.proxy.SqliteStorage',
   'Ext.data.reader.Array'
],

initDb: function() {
Ext.ns('DbConnection');

this.DbConnection = Ext.create('Sqlite.Connection', {
  dbName: 'ConsultLiteApp',
  dbDescription: 'ConsultLiteApp Database',
  dbVersion: '1.0',
  dbSize: 200000,
});
},

getConnection: function() {
  if(!Ext.isDefined(this.DbConnection)) this.initDb();
  return this.DbConnection;
}
});
```

My Model file in which is i have used sqllite proxy

```
Ext.define('ConsultLite.model.Credential', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
xtype: 'Credential',
config: {
fields: [
    { name : 'id',  type : 'int' },
    { name: 'email', type: 'string'},
    { name: 'password', type: 'string'}
],
proxy: {
    type: 'sqlitestorage',
    dbConfig: {
        tablename: 'credential',
        dbConn: ConsultLite.util.InitSQLite.getConnection()
    }
   },
  },
});
```

After executing sencha command "sencha app build production" above error come